# Trying to define constructors. Code E0513 a value of type "float" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "float*"

Tags: c++

After adding data members I get Code E0513 Line 49 a value of type "float" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "float*"

Found post on SO with the same issue so I tried using const_cast Line 44 and that didn't help either.gave me Code E0077 Line 44 no storage class or type specifier

I've tried to give as much information as possible. And the code was in three separate files.  Not sure if this single file is in the correct format.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Class declaration usually in header

class Float_Array
{
public:
    // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~      Constructors
    // Creat a Float_Array with zero elements.
    Float_Array();

    // Create a Float_array with 'size' elements.
    Float_Array(int size);

    // Creat3 a Float_Array from another Float_Array --
    // Confirm no memory leaks!
    Float_Array(const Float_Array& rhs);

    // Free dynamic memory.
    ~Float_Array();
    // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~      Member functions 
    // Define how a Float_Array shall be assigned to another Float_Array-- be sure to prevent memory leaks
    // Is this a user defined type.
    Float_Array& operator=(const Float_Array& rhs);

    //  Resize the Float_Array to a new size.
    void resize(int new_size);

    // Return the number of the elements in the array.
    int size();

    // Overload bracket operator so client can index into FloatArray objects and access the elements.
    float& operator [] (int i);

private:
    //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~      Class Data Members
    float* m_data_ptr; // Pointer to array of floats (dynamic memory)
    int     m_size;  // The number of elements in the array.

};

float* m_data_ptr;
m_data_ptr = const_cast<float*>(m_data_ptr); // ~~~~  Line 44 E0077 Added this line caused this error

// empty class definition
Float_Array::Float_Array() // ~~~~
{
    m_data_ptr = 0.0f; //~~~~ Line 49 E0513 ~~~~ a value of type "float" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "float*"
    m_size = 0;
}

// Create array with size elements see array in template codelite page 136
// class definition
Float_Array::Float_Array(int size)
{
    m_size = size;
}


// empty class definition
Float_Array::Float_Array(const Float_Array& rhs)
{

}
// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~      Function definition
int* ResizeArray(int* array, int oldSize, int newSize)
{


    // Create an array with the new size.
    int* newArray = new int[newSize];

    // New array is a greater size than old array.
    if (newSize >= oldSize)
    {
        // Copy old elements to new array.
        for (int i = 0; i < oldSize; ++i)
            newArray[i] = array[i];
    }

    // New array is a lesser size than old array.
    else // newSize < oldSize
    {
        // Copy as many old elements to new array as can fit.
        for (int i = 0; i < newSize; ++i)
            newArray[i] = array[i];
    }

    // Delete the old array.
    delete[] array;

    // Return a pointer to the new array.
    return newArray;
}

void Print_Float_Array(Float_Array& fa)
{
    cout << "{ ";

    for (int i = 0; i < fa.size(); ++i)
        cout << fa[i] << " ";

    cout << "}" << endl << endl;
}
```

Comment: In `m_data_ptr = 0.0f;` `m_data_ptr` is a pointer and pointer's gonna point. You have to give it an address to point at. `0.0f` is [a floating point literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal). It's just a value that you could assign to anything that can accept a float. It's not an address and it doesn't even have an address because it doesn't really exist. You can't point at it. Consider pointing `m_data_ptr` at `nullptr` to signify that there isn't an array yet.

Comment: You're defining two different variables with the name `m_data_ptr`. And you try to assign (not initialize) the one in the global scope outside any function, which is not allowed. Together with multiple other problems it really seems to me that you have missed some very basic parts when studying.

Comment: m_data_ptr = NULL; m_size = 0; Worked perfectly I removed the cast as well.  I think I tried that in the past but I didn't clean or rebuild my solution.  Could that have caused it?  Thank you both for taking the time to help.